# Dedicated server probability

Tags: database, dedicated-server

I have 4 websites and i plan to move them on two dedicated servers. This is the config of the dedicated servers:
Core2Duo E8400 3.0 GHz
8 GB DDR2-800 SDRAM
250 GB SATA HDD (7200 RPM)
2 TB Bandwidth
10 Mbps Uplink Port Speed

In terms of speed, should i put the website files on a dedicated server and their databases on the other dedicated servers. 
Or
Server 1: (website1 + database) and (website2 + database)
Server 2: (website3 + database) and (website4 + database)
This last option seems more logic to me...just asking because i want to make the right decision.

Answer (score 0):

Where to you expect growth to occur? More sites and associated databases? More largeish files getting uploaded to sites? Lots of data stored in your databases? More visitors coming to existing sites?

Use the answers to these questions to plan what will make scaling in the future easier, taking into account what downtime is allowed to the sites for any changes that may be needed. Also find out if the servers have a faster internal connection. Is billing based on internet traffic, or traffic out the server even if its just going to the other server?